# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt x}{1+x} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

> How to evaluate $$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt x}{1+x} dx$$

It's actually part of a bigger evaluation. I got stuck here. What should I do to proceed?

The previous integral was:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{u^2}{1+u^2} du$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{u^2}{1 + u^2} = \frac{1 + u^2}{1 + u^2} - \frac{1}{1 + u^2}$.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}=1-\frac{1}{1+u^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the change of variable $t = \sqrt{x}$.

$$I:=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1 + x}dx =_{(t = \sqrt{x})} \int_0^1\frac{2t^2}{1 + t^2}dt = 2\int_0^1\frac{-1 + 1 + t^2}{1 + t^2}dt = 2\int_0^1dt - 2\int_0^1\frac{1}{1 + t^2}dt = 2(1 - 0) - 2(\arctan(1) - \arctan(0)) = 2 - 2(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 2 - \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Weird. I just came from there :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Write $$\frac{u^2}{1 + u^2} = \frac{u^2 + 1 - 1}{1 + u^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + u^2}$$

Remember that $\frac{d}{dx} (\arctan x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$.

Comment: Cool.. Thank you Aaaron

Comment: You're welcome!